# Value in DF based on value and condition from another DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

```
df1=pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=['2020-12-31 23:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 01:00:00'])

df2=pandas.DataFrame([['2020-01-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00',70],['2021-01-01 00:00:00','2022-01-01 00:00:00',65]],columns=['From','To','Value'])
```

I then want to get this:

```
pandas.DataFrame([[1,70],[2,65],[3,65]],index=['2020-12-31 23:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 01:00:00'])
```

In other words for all dates in df1.index in want to get the 'Value' from df2 based on the condition that df1.index>=df2[From] & df1.index<df2[To]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pd.IntervalIndex

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=['2020-12-31 23:00:00','2021-01-01 
    00:00:00','2021-01-01 01:00:00'])

df2=pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-01 00:00:00','2021-01-01 00:00:00',70],['2021-01-01 00:00:00','2022-01-01 00:00:00',65]],columns=['From','To','Value'])

df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df2.From = pd.to_datetime(df2.From)
df2.To = pd.to_datetime(df2.To)

df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.From,df2.To,"left")

df1[1] = df2.loc[df1.index].Value.to_numpy()

df1
```

Output:

```
                    0    1
2020-12-31 23:00:00 1   70
2021-01-01 00:00:00 2   65
2021-01-01 01:00:00 3   65
```